# serialize the array of kmeans.labels_ array when use scikit learn

Tags: arrays, scikit-learn

Each time i execute the k-mean program. I got an array like [5 0 0 0 4 4 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 0 0 0 0 4 2 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 4 2 1 3 0 0 0 5 0 0 4 2 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 2 1 3 0 0 0 2 3].

Next time i execute it ,i got [1 2 2 2 4 4 5 5 0 0 0 3 3 2 2 2 2 4 5 0 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 5 0 3 2 2 2 1 2
 2 4 5 0 3 2 2 2 2 2 4 5 0 3 2 2 2 5 3].

I want the first category label of the would be 0 and second be 1.
like [0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 3 5]

do anyone knows about the algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would want to do this because all groups are interchangeable but if you really need it, here is a way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

groups = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3])
```

First, get order of appearance of values in groups: 1 appears first, then 2, then 4 etc

```
groups_in_order = pd.unique(groups)
# array([1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 3])
```

Order that new array: 0 appears in index 4, 1 in index 0 etc

```
right_order = np.argsort(groups_in_order)
# array([4, 0, 1, 5, 2, 3])
```

Finally reorder `group` using `right_order` and a list comprehension

```
[ right_order[i] for i in groups]

#[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,
# 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1,
# 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 0,
# 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
# 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot. I use kmeans to write some excel form  with coordinate of text. i take coordinate as fearture with kmeans. The serialization is matter when I write text into column with origin structure of form  .I use a dict() way too.

```
SerialCount=0
ddiicctt={}
for ele in labelnumpyArray:
    print(ele)
    if ele not in ddiicctt:
        ddiicctt[ele]=SerialCount
        SerialCount+=1
print(ddiicctt)
```